# vim to start edit right below the cursor

Tags: vim, editors

In the current behaviour of vim, at least on Ubuntu, it will clean the screen and make new edit window. I would like to just start right below the cursor, for example:

> $vi test.txt
> [start editing by press i]

Is it possible to achieve this with vim? If not then which terminal editor can do it?

Comment: Welcome, do you mean by pressing "o" instead of "i"?

Comment: I mean "i". Use "o" will add a new line.

Comment: You might want to check [`ed`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_(text_editor)) out.